# Access an element inside a list, given by a variable Python

Tags: python, list, token

I am pretending to obtain a specific element in a lists, but I receive and error when I try to do this: `print linesqueryfile[queryindex]`, `linesqueryfile` is a list and `queryindex` is the number of element that I want, I want further to split it in tokens and obtain and specific element in the token's list.

I'm new to python so I don't know how to do this, How's the sintaxis for accessing an element from a list.

This is my code:

```
n=len(linesfile)

for i in range(0,n):
    tokens = re.split('\s+', linesfile[i])
    queryindex = tokens[1]  
    subjectindex = tokens[2]  

    print queryindex
    print subjectindex

    print linesqueryfile[queryindex]
    print linessubjectfile[subjectindex]

    tokens = split('\s+', linesqueryfile[queryindex])
    queryseqstr = tokens[5]
```

`linesfile` sample:

```
1 12751 92 566
1 7415 88 566
1 1643 87 566
1 16647 83 566
1 13697 82 566
1 13737 82 566
1 13723 82 566
1 20413 82 566
1 22113 82 566
1 20590 80 566
2 11612 1657 2008
2 6084 1305 2008
2 6085 1292 2008
2 6087 1290 2008
2 6086 1283 2008
2 11627 1276 2008
2 11633 1275 2008
2 11634 1274 2008
2 11629 1268 2008
2 11599 1267 2008
3 11621 1794 2061
3 11623 1623 2061
```

Comment: what does `linesfile` look like?

Comment: We're missing just a small amount of info before we can really help.  What does the data look like going in, and what are in linesqueryfile and linessubjectfile.  From what we've got so far, it looks like basic slicing, but if you can add the extra info it'll help you get a good response.

Comment: Syntax appears ok, what is it doing, or not doing...

Comment: `re.split()` return a list of string, if `linesqueryfile` is a list, you can't use a string as an index.

Comment: edited linesfile content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your error. I am guessing  that queryindex and subjectindex are string numbers. If not, please provide your error.

```
print linesqueryfile[int(queryindex)]
print linessubjectfile[int(subjectindex)]
```

or make:

```
queryindex = int(tokens[1])  
subjectindex = int(tokens[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting `queryindex` and `queryindex` to integers:

```
n=len(linesfile)

for i in range(0,n):
    tokens = re.split('\s+', linesfile[i])
    queryindex = int(tokens[1])
    subjectindex = int(tokens[2])

    print queryindex
    print subjectindex

    print linesqueryfile[queryindex]
    print linessubjectfile[subjectindex]

    tokens = split('\s+', linesqueryfile[queryindex])
    queryseqstr = tokens[5]
```